# in app purchase: how to finish all transactions in SKPaymentQueue?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have the problem that when the app loses network after purchasing an in app consumable, `finishTransaction` doesn't work. I'm calling `finishTransaction` (still without internet connection), but the next time the app starts and I'm setting

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:...];
```

the user is asked for the App Store password. My problem here is that I don't know what exactly he purchased here. If he presses cancel here, everything's fine, but if the user enters password, he is billed and doesn't get anything for it. So I would prefer cancel all pending transactions.

I already tried with

```
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions) {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}
```

but `[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions` is empty here. Are there any other possibilities to prevent the user from being asked but to cancel all pending transactions?

Comment: You have the `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` delegate method implemented right?

Comment: Why don't you know what they purchased?  The product is in the payment which is provided in the transaction.

Comment: @adam10603 I have them implemented, it's called with status failed, I'm doing a ```finishTransaction``` there but as I mentioned without internet connection.

Comment: @Paulw11 it's only one in app product, but the user can buy different services with it. Think of it as an id stored on our server the user likes to unlock.

Comment: If it is a consumable then typically this is used to update some "balance". This balance is then used to purchase services. You need to verify whether this transaction has already updated the balance or not

Comment: @Paulw11 it's really hard to explain, but I need information that I don't have after app restart. The user buys a service which unlocks something online in his user account, but with that lots of data is sent. Normally after in app is successful, the app makes a server call with that data.

Comment: You need to correlate the payment transaction id with a transaction on your server to determine which event this purchase corresponds to.  It sounds like you may need to rethink your design. The ability to complete transactions after app restarts is a requirement

Comment: this doesn't answer my initial question... it's irritating that sometimes the user is asked for the password and sometimes he isn't. if the user cancels the initial purchase, the transaction status is ```failed``` as well but the user isn't asked again. But if the network connection is lost, the user is asked again. So I'd like to have it always the same way

Comment: Perhaps the reason that `[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions` is empty is because of [this line in Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506026-transactions): "The value of this property [-transactions] is undefined when there are no observers attached to the payment queue."?

Comment: I am looking for a similar answer. My question is how can I know if all of my transaction has finished? I am finishing every transaction in `case .purchased:, case .restored:, & .failed:` inside of `updatedTransactions` delegate. I tried to cancel them all inside of `removedTransactions` delegate as well. But If my user has a massive transactions like more than 150, then after restoring, if I try to purchase a product immediately, inside `updatedTransactions ` delegate it triggers `case .restored:` instead of `case .purchased:`!

Comment: If I take some moment to finish all the transactions, then it works fine again. This means it triggers `case .purchased:`. So I am assuming the problem is, it's not been finishing all my transactions properly. So I need to know If all transactions have finished for a single operation. Either restore or purchase. Any suggestions?